# Finding min value by two keys

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have array with objects

```
    const data = [
  { "bankNumber": 1, "calculatedFee":   0, "feeNumber":  4, "group": "1" },
  { "bankNumber": 1, "calculatedFee": 147, "feeNumber":  6, "group": "1" },
  { "bankNumber": 1, "calculatedFee":  20, "feeNumber": 10, "group": "1" },
  { "bankNumber": 1, "calculatedFee":  200, "feeNumber": 10, "group": "2"},
  { "bankNumber": 1, "calculatedFee":  20, "feeNumber": 10, "group": "2" },
  { "bankNumber": 2, "calculatedFee":  10, "feeNumber": 10, "group": "3" },
  { "bankNumber": 2, "calculatedFee": 100, "feeNumber": 10, "group": "3" },
  { "bankNumber": 3, "calculatedFee": 100, "feeNumber": 10, "group": "2" },
]
```

I would like to filter this data to get the smallest value calculatedFee with one group and bankNumber. For example calculatedFee = 0 is the smallest for group 1 and bankNumber 1, calculatedFee = 10 is the smallest for group 3 and bankNumber 2,. However, I have no idea what function to create in JavaScript to get such results

Comment: To filter data, use the function filter. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) with an object to store the minimum fee for each combination of `bankNumber` and `group`.

```js
const data=[{bankNumber:1,calculatedFee:0,feeNumber:4,group:"1"},{bankNumber:1,calculatedFee:147,feeNumber:6,group:"1"},{bankNumber:1,calculatedFee:20,feeNumber:10,group:"1"},{bankNumber:1,calculatedFee:200,feeNumber:10,group:"2"},{bankNumber:1,calculatedFee:20,feeNumber:10,group:"2"},{bankNumber:2,calculatedFee:10,feeNumber:10,group:"3"},{bankNumber:2,calculatedFee:100,feeNumber:10,group:"3"},{bankNumber:3,calculatedFee:100,feeNumber:10,group:"2"},];
const res = data.reduce((acc, {bankNumber, group, calculatedFee}) => {
  (acc[bankNumber] ??= {})[group] = Math.min(acc[bankNumber][group] ?? Infinity, calculatedFee);
  return acc;
}, {});
for (const [bank, vals] of Object.entries(res)) 
  for (const [group, fee] of Object.entries(vals)) 
    console.log('Bank', bank, 'Group', group, 'Min fee', fee);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `Math.min()` along with `filter()` and `map()`

```js
const data = [
  { "bankNumber": 1, "calculatedFee":   0, "feeNumber":  4, "group": "1" },
  { "bankNumber": 1, "calculatedFee": 147, "feeNumber":  6, "group": "1" },
  { "bankNumber": 1, "calculatedFee":  20, "feeNumber": 10, "group": "1" },
  { "bankNumber": 1, "calculatedFee":  200, "feeNumber": 10, "group": "2"},
  { "bankNumber": 1, "calculatedFee":  20, "feeNumber": 10, "group": "2" },
  { "bankNumber": 2, "calculatedFee":  10, "feeNumber": 10, "group": "3" },
  { "bankNumber": 2, "calculatedFee": 100, "feeNumber": 10, "group": "3" },
  { "bankNumber": 3, "calculatedFee": 100, "feeNumber": 10, "group": "2" },
]

const result = Math.min(...data.filter(i => i.group === '3' && i.bankNumber === 2).map(i => i.calculatedFee))

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
    const data = [
    { "bankNumber": 1, "calculatedFee":   0, "feeNumber":  4, "group": "1" },
    { "bankNumber": 1, "calculatedFee": 147, "feeNumber":  6, "group": "1" },
    { "bankNumber": 1, "calculatedFee":  20, "feeNumber": 10, "group": "1" },
    { "bankNumber": 1, "calculatedFee":  200, "feeNumber": 10, "group": "2"},
    { "bankNumber": 1, "calculatedFee":  20, "feeNumber": 10, "group": "2" },
    { "bankNumber": 2, "calculatedFee":  10, "feeNumber": 10, "group": "3" },
    { "bankNumber": 2, "calculatedFee": 100, "feeNumber": 10, "group": "3" },
    { "bankNumber": 3, "calculatedFee": 100, "feeNumber": 10, "group": "2" },
  ]
  data.sort((a, b) => {
    return a.calculatedFee - b.calculatedFee;
    
  });
 console.log(data)
```